Failed loading model in LM Studio
Trying to load in LM Studio the "TheBloke • mistral instruct v0 1 7B q3_k_s gguf" I get the following message.
Failed to load model
Error message
"llama.cpp error: 'vk::Device::createShaderModule: ErrorInitializationFailed'"
How can I fix this?
{
  "title": "Failed to load model",
  "cause": "llama.cpp error: 'vk::Device::createShaderModule: ErrorInitializationFailed'",
  "errorData": {
    "n_ctx": 2048,
    "n_batch": 512,
    "n_gpu_layers": 10
  },
  "data": {
    "memory": {
      "ram_capacity": "7.55 GB",
      "ram_unused": "552.34 MB"
    },
    "gpu": {
      "gpu_names": [
        "AMD Radeon(TM) RX Vega 10 Graphics"
      ],
      "vram_recommended_capacity": 0,
      "vram_unused": 0
    },
    "os": {
      "platform": "win32",
      "version": "10.0.19045"
    },
    "app": {
      "version": "0.2.31",
      "downloadsDir": "C:\\Users\\ianba\\.cache\\lm-studio\\models"
    },
    "model": {}
  }
}```

Loading the model "TheBloke • mistral instruct v0 1 7B q3_k_s gguf" I get the error message
Error message
"llama.cpp error: 'vk::Device::createShaderModule: ErrorInitializationFailed'"


Note this is not a solution but a comment and the comment section is not big enough to accommodate a big one, so writing in the answer section.
The error you mentioned could be because of one or more of following reasons.

Your GPU is either unsupported or not configured with the latest/supported driver versions. Make sure you have the supported drivers installed.
You need to go through the complete log if you have access to that. Sometimes, it is not the actual GPU/Hardware that causes the problem.
Refering to the fields in the errorData , it might be the case that the configuration parameters are not acceptable, did you try with other values of number of layers, context point etc? Start with smaller/simpler values. Also I would suggest you to run any example project if possible.

Good Luck!
